# How properly enqueue a child theme

Tags: wordpress

I've been trying to develop a simple child theme to tweak a few things on my website which currently uses the vantage theme. So far, I've had little success.

The two files (style.css and function.php) I've created only have a few lines of code, but I'm still unable to pinpoint the problem.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_styles', 
PHP_INT_MAX);
function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', 
get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
?>



/*
Theme Name: vantage-child
Template: Vantage
*/
body {
color:aqua; 
}
```

I suspect the problem is with the enqueueing in the PHP file, but all configurations that I have found on the internet and the wordpress codex don't seem to work on my site. When I activate the child theme created by my code, the site reverts to ONLY the styles in my child theme's stylesheet, instead of falling back on the parent theme's stylesheet when no styles are specified in the child theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For child theme you can first need to create folder with themename-child.
- Then you have to create style.css file.
- Put the following lines in your style.css

  `/*
    Theme Name:   Twenty Fourteen Child
    Theme URI:    http://yourwebsite.com/twentyfourteen-child/
    Description:  My first child theme, based on Twenty Fourteen
    Author:       Joshi Niket
   Template:      twentyfourteen
   Text Domain:   twenty-fourteen-child
  */`
- Then create functions.php in child theme folder and put the following code.

  `<?php
       add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
       function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
         wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
       }
  ?>`
- Please check following link to make child theme with proper steps, i have added few here to guid you.[ReferenceLink](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme/)

Thank you ,I hope this helps you.

Comment: This seems like a solid answer, but it's still not entirely fixing the problem in my case. Do I just copy paste the PHP above into my functions.php file, or should I customize it based on the theme I'm working with? For example, if the parent theme is "twentyfifteen" do I change the "function my_theme_enqueue_styles()" to "function twentyfifteen_enqueue_styles()"? And should 'parent-style' be "twentyfifteen-style'?

Comment: Yes mate you can use that according to your theme because it's fully tested and work for me, but make sure style.css file name never get change as per theme name or whatever

Comment: Welcome @JakeDoe I'm happy to hear this

Answer (score 0):

Please install and create child theme by using [One-Click Child Theme](https://wordpress.org/plugins/one-click-child-theme/.)

plugin. This is very easy to use